# Phone gap -Apple rejects the app ITMS 90096 errors with Splash Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, iphone-5

I am trying to deploy an app to App Store however Apple rejects the app.

I am getting an error `ITMS :90096` which is specific to 4 inch splash screen for iPhone 5.

I have added the splash into the app and referred it into the `config.xml`.

I have tried various solutions on SO and also other sites but no luck. 
I am unsure how to fix it and its getting real frustrating now. Can someone help?

The error  [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are referring Splash images in Config.xml rather than applying in AssetManager.
Click on your project, General-> App Icon and Launch images.
[image]

Comment: His question is tagged with Cordova which is why he is using the config.xml. This is the recommended way to specify splash images in Cordova as documented at http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/config_ref_images.md.html.

Comment: I didnt tell not to use config.xml, i just told the better solution

Comment: You asked why he was referring to splash images in the config.xml, I told you why.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to start with a new config.xml from the latest "cordova start" package on github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start).

(If this is an insufficient answer, please post your current config.xml file so we can see what is wrong)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ionic to build the app.
You can fix this issue by execute "ionic resources".
the issue is caused by the image size of Default-568h@2x~iphone.png is not 640*1136.
steps to create all size of splashscreens and icons:
1.create a new ionic app by "ionic start myApp tabs"
2.place one splash screen image and one icon to /myApp/resources/ folder
3.execute "ionic resources", this command will generated all size of images and icons that are required by ios.

Answer (score 0):

When uploading an app built with Phonegap Build I was getting this error message with a slightly different text, 'must include a launch image referenced in the Info.plist under UILaunchImages with a UILaunchImageSize value set to {320, 568}.'

I found a workaround by changing phonegap-version in config.xml to cli-6.5.0. ie.

```
<preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-6.5.0' />
```

It seems this is an Apple bug.